# Django datetime form field, datetime picker

Tags: jquery, django, forms, datetime

I need to implement a datetime picker in an html form so I can insert datetime data into my database. I'm using django forms to display the form. First of all, I need a datetime field in the form, which I've tried overtly and covertly to make it work, but it doesn't. I'm would like to avoid third party plugins but I haven't found any native datetime picker from jQuery. I've read about datepicker in django so that would also be an option, but I know not yet how to implement it.

Also, what would be the best type of data in the django form? My atempt was:

```
lastcheck = forms.DateField(label='Última Comprobación', input_formats=['%Y-%m-%d', '%Y.%m.%d' ])
```

Thanks in advanced!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [django-datetime-widget](https://github.com/asaglimbeni/django-datetime-widget). There are examples showing how to use it.

For instance, if you want to use it in a form just define a field with the right `widget` attribute, like this:

```
class MyForm(ModelForm):
    dateTimeOptions = {
        'format': 'dd/mm/yyyy HH:ii P',
        'autoclose': True,
        'showMeridian' : True
     }

    class Meta:
        model = YourModel
        fields = "__all__"
        widgets = {
            'YourDateTimeField': DateWidget(attrs = {'id':'id_dateTimeField'}, bootstrap_version=3, usel10n=True)
}
```

In your view you just process the field `YourDateTimeField` like a normal field assuming it has been defined in your model as a DateField.

Comment: Would there be a way of using jQuery on the template input. I mean accessing the html generated?